# WPF ItemsControl with a single Source and DataType, but multiple DataTemplates not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

My ItemsCOntrol below has two `DataTemplates`, one source, that contains one `DataType` named Conduits.
If I remove either one of the `DataTemplates` then it works.
With both I get the following error.

```
ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 
'DataTemplateKey(Drain.Models.Cad.Conduit)'  Key being added: 
'DataTemplateKey(Drain.Models.Cad.Conduit)'
```

The only difference between the two `DataTemplates` is that one gets it's data from `UsPoints` within Conduits and the other `DsPoints`, also within Conduits.

I could create two separate `ItemsControls` but I already have eight, and I'm unsure if there is any harm solving such issues by creating additional `ItemControls` in terms of performance?

Any recommendations on how I should proceed?

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ConduitHandles">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ConduitHandlesUS" Source="{Binding Path=NetworkMain.Conduits}"></CollectionViewSource>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Conduit}">
                <Polygon 
                    Stroke="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Handle}"
                    Fill="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Handle}"
                    StrokeThickness="1" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Visible, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='Visible'}"
                    Points="{Binding UsPoint, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HandleConverter}}">
                </Polygon>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cad:Conduit}">
                <Polygon 
                    Stroke="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Handle}"
                    Fill="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectColour}, ConverterParameter=Handle}"
                    StrokeThickness="1" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Visible, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='Visible'}"
                    Points="{Binding DsPoint, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HandleConverter}}">
                </Polygon>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConduitHandlesUS}}"></CollectionContainer>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas 
                    ClipToBounds="true">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataType` property of a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary automatically generates a Dictionary Key. Two identical DataType values will obviously create two identical keys, which is not allowed.

In order to use different DataTemplates for items of the same type, you would have to use a `DataTemplateSelector` and assign it to the `ItemTemplateSelector` property of the ItemsControl.

There must however be a means to decide which DataTemplate to chose for a specific item, e.g. an item property:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    if (item is Conduit conduit)
    {
        return conduit.UsPoints != null
            ? UsPointsDataTemplate
            : DsPointsDataTemplate;
    }

    return null;
}
```